# Explain to me where the 'x' in hexadecimal '0xf0' comes from

Tags: java, hex

*Hexadecimal* goes from `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F`.

I am confused as to where the `'x'` in `'0x0f'` comes from.

And if `'0x0f' = '0000 1111'` or `'15'` why not just write `'0f'`.

Pretty sure this is universal across most languages, but if not, I'm using Java.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not actually universal (though it's common). For example, in some assembly languages you'll see `$1234`.

Comment: This comes from `C` which does the same.  This is called "hexadecimal"  and you could use `h` but this is very close to `g`, `e` cannot be used as it is used in hex already `x` is obviously different.

Comment: Hexadecimal actually only has 16 digits (0-9, A-F), not 17 like you listed. `G` is not a hexadecimal digit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's historic, with Java inheriting that syntax from C.

The `x` is necessary to distinguish 0377 (for example) from 0x377, where the leading zero in the former indicates that it's in octal (base 8):

```
   377 - base 10
  0377 - base 8
 0x377 - base 16
```

Comment: +1 for simple, example-followed answer

Answer (score 1):

See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html):

> In a hexadecimal or binary literal, the integer is only denoted by the
>   digits after the 0x or 0b characters and before any type suffix.
>   Therefore, underscores may not appear immediately after 0x or 0b, or
>   after the last digit in the numeral.

It's used in order to distinguish between bases.